# Creating a Responsive Table With Data from phpmysql

Tags: php, css, bootstrap-4

The below table prints data form a mysql db. Is it possible to make it responsive to adapt to even the smallest devices without losing the image. I am studying bootstrap to see how it can work.

```
<style> 
body { margin: 0; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; } 
.content { margin: auto; width: 99.8%; height:79.8%; border: 1px solid green; padding: 10px; background-color: magenta; }
</style> 
<div class="content">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
       <?php
        print "<table border=1 width=100%>"; 
        print "<td width=10px height=auto bgcolor=#00FF33>" . $row['id'] . "</td>"; 
        print "<td width=200px height=200px>"."<a href='".$row['image']."'><img src=".$row['image']."width=100% height=100%</a>" ."</td>";
    print "<td>"; 
        print "<table border=1 width=100%>"; 
        print "<tr>";
        print "<td>" . $row['imagename'] . "</td>";
        print "</tr>"; 
        print "<tr>";
        print "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
        print "</tr>"; 
        print "<tr>";
        print "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";
        print "</tr>";
        print "<tr>";
        print "<td>" . $row['useremail'] . "</td>";
        print "</tr>";
        print "<tr>";
        print "<td>" . $row['userphone'] . "</td>";
        print "</tr>";
        print "<tr>";
        print "<td>"."<a href='id=$uniqueid' >More Details</a>"."</td>";
        print "</tr>";
        print "<tr>";
        print "<td>"."<a href='id=$uniqueid' >Contact Seller</a>"."</td>";
        print "</tr>"; 
        print "</table>"; 
        print "</td>"; 
        print "</table>"; 
        print "<br />";
      ?>    
    </div>
```

Comment: You can use the datatables. https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap4

Comment: Thanks @alka singla Sorry this didnt help

Answer (score 0):

Incase you're using bootstrap just add "table table-responsive" to your table class

```
<table class="table table-responsive">
```

Comment: Thanks @barlevin he image is dissapearing completely